# Different Alignments in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have three divs: a nav bar, a webgl player, and a panel. I want the navbar at the top, and beneath it the panel aligned to the right hand side of the screen, and the webgl player to be centered vertically and horizontally in the remaining space.

`items-center` sucessefully centers things vertically.

For the correct horizonal positioning, so far I have tried `justify-between` which successfully places the panel against the right edge, but also places the webgl player against the left edge of the screen, which is undesirable.

`justify-center` places them both in the middle, wherein I expected `place-self-end` on the right-hand element to correctly place it, but it didn't move at all.

Minimal Code example:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="bg-green-500 py-12 flex flex-col justify-center"></div>
  <div class="flex flex-row justify-center items-center">
    <div class="bg-blue-500 w-80 h-60 center"></div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-80 h-screen "></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can also be found here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/y3uXkVYcWs

Desired Result:
[image: Desired Layout]
Where Green is Navbar, Blue is first div, Red is second div.

Answer (score 0):

After writing all of this, I finally found this answer: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties)

This says to drop any `justify` and `items-center` and instead use `margin: auto` on the blue element

## HTML

```html
<div class="flex flex-col">
  <div class="bg-green-500 py-12 flex flex-col"></div>
  <div class="flex flex-row justify-center">
    <div class="bg-blue-500 w-80 h-60 center" id="webglPlayer"></div>
    <div class="bg-red-500 w-80 h-screen" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

#webglPlayer {
    margin: auto;
}
```